# How to use my FFMPEG code in Automator (Mac)

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, automator

I have an ffmpeg code that converts .mov files to .mp4 files. I would like to set up a 'watch folder' system on my mac, so that when I drop files into a specific folder, it will automatically convert the file using my FFMPEG code.

I have tried to add my FFMPEG code into the Automator app (mac) as a shell script, but it did not work and gave me the error **"The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “zsh:3: no matches found: *.mov”"**

The FFMPEG code that I am using is...

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -ss 4 -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 20M -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac "mp4/${i%.*}.mp4"; done;
```

Is anyone able to help me work out why this is not working please?

Greatly appreciated!

Best,
John

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
for i in *.mov
```

What directory is that executing in?

Instead, use one of the Finder automator actions like "Get Selected Finder Items" or "Ask for Finder Items" to select the files you want frobbed by ffmpeg. Add one before the Run Shell Script action so it acts as input.